# General routing in ASP.NET WebForms, to change "/cpanel/" to "/marketer/"

Tags: asp.net, routes, url-rewriting

Consider this scenario, in which, all of the incoming links in the pattern of `/cpanel/x` should be converted (rewrited) to `/marketer/x`, where `x` stands for the rest of the URL. Examples are:

1. `/cpanel/coupons.aspx` to `/marketer/coupons.aspx`
2. `/cpanel/sold.aspx?year=2010&product=camera` to /marketer/sold.aspx?year=2010&product=camera`

This seems like a general URL rewriting, and we've done it using `HttpContext.Current.RewritePath` and an HTTP module. However, I also want to know if this can  be done using ASP.NET Routing feature, in web forms?

Requirements are:

1. How to define route rule
2. How to generate URLs relating to this route rule

Answer (score 1):

** EDITED AFTER COMMENT **

You can do this using Routing with web forms. To get your desired functionality that could rewrite 10,000 URL's just swapping the "cpanel" for "marketer", you need to use a wildcard. To do this, in your Global.asax file add the following namespace and the method:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //--- format ("Name", "Route", "Handler")
    routes.MapPageRoute("cPanel", "marketer/{*RouteCPanel}", "~/cpanel/{*RouteCPanel}");
}
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Notice the {*RouteCPanel} that is your wildcard and that means to read everything from that point in the URL to the end, no matter what is there. The way we have it setup is you can put any URL that has "/marketer/...." and it will be rewritten to "/cpanel/....."

Hope this helps. Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for your help. But this method doesn't support DRY (do not repeat yourself) principal, cause there is no centralization here. Imagine that I have 10,000 pages which need to be routed from `coupon` to `marketer`. What do you do then?